# What does * mean in the argument of np array shape? For example, np.multiply(*arr.shape)?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm wondering what * mean in this context. I've looked in the documentation too, but I'm still not too sure what it means. I've attached some code below for context.

(As an aside, I've also seen this used PyTorch tensors' .view() or .reshape_() method. Wondering if this is the same meaning.)

documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html

```
def one_hot_encode(arr, n_labels):

    one_hot = np.zeros((np.multiply(*arr.shape), n_labels), dtype=np.float32)

    one_hot[np.arange(one_hot.shape[0]), arr.flatten()] = 1.

    one_hot = one_hot.reshape((*arr.shape, n_labels))

    return one_hot
```

Comment: ...wow, there's a lot of things this could be a duplicate of.

Comment: ^ Admittedly it is hard to search for

Comment: Yes. Thanks, either ways, I'll read those.

Comment: In this context it means, expand the `arr.shape` tuple into the two arguments that `np.multiply` takes.  In other words, `np.multiply(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1])`, or equivalently `arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1]`.  I think `np.prod(x.shape)` is a better expression.